# Is it possible to get authorized on twitter and change twitter status without asking users to enter PIN?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to get authorized on twitter and change twitter status without asking users to enter PIN ? Or can i store access token to use it when user starts application next time ?

Comment: Deprecated, new people coming across this thread: try this new OAuth Tutorial: http://goo.gl/99vpL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also activate xAuth authentification. In order to do that you have to create your twitter app and ask xAuth activation to Twitter.